# Rendering css to screen and debug problem

Tags: css, debug

i got a website here that i am building up [HERE](http://studioteknik.co/solertia.ca/en/)

the right arrow, in chrome, is LOW as you can see [here](http://studioteknik.co/solertia.ca/bug.jpg)

but when i debug it with the debugger and check float on/off, it comeback to the place it should be...

so the question is, what is the problem ? the CSS, the browser, the debugger the system (mac?) or HTML... if need your light !... thanks in advance

Comment: Its a bug in chrome, so basically its the browser's problem. Can you report this? If not - mind if I do?

Comment: If you think it's a bug... OK... but i ask it here because there is CSS/HTML expert that know all the trick to make css behave good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its an old bug in Chrome.

In order to solve your problem though - you just need to add this CSS (append to the one you already have in place):

```
.fleche {
    float: none !important;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

With inline-blocks - you don't need floats to keep them on the same line.

Comment: I have try, did not fix the problem. but some friend suggest floating the .bs-wrapper, and it fix it !